# Spring Advice is not applied for recursed beans

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I made a simple app with the following dependency tree for components:

```
Service1 injects Service2(via constructor)
Service2 injects SomeContext(via setter)
SomContext injects Service1(via setter)
Advisor is for Service1
```

So when spring tries to construct Service1 or Service2 it automatically tries to apply advise, but there is a check in spring  -  isCurrentlyInCreation (in BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java), so the bean for which it tries to apply advise is still it creation and skips advise applying.

I know that recurse of bean is a bad way of design but it is hard to decouple now and refactor.

I fix this issue with the help of factorybean for SomeContext and loading of Service1 when needed via applicationcontext(applicationcontextaware), but maybe someone knows better solution?

Comment: What Advice are you trying to apply and how do you configure it in the spring context? Please show some code regarding the Advice, the PublishService and the spring bean xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this if you apply compile time weaving instead of load time weaving. Here are two posts that can get you started:

- [Spring, Aspects, @Configurable and Compile Time Weaving using maven](http://www.chrissearle.org/blog/technical/spring_aspects_configurable_and_compile_time_weaving_using_maven)
- [Spring @Transactional: Verifying transaction support / Local method calls](http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/01/spring-transactional-checking-for-transaction-support-and-local-method-calls/)